# Converting .docx to .txt in C++

Tags: c++, bash

Apologies for the duplicated (I think) question, new to C++ and have had a look around but still stuck!

I have found a bash script that takes a .docx file and outputs the plain text.

```
unzip -p filename.docx word/document.xml | sed -e 's/<[^>]\{1,\}>//g; s/[^[:print:]]\{1,\}//g'
```

This works great over bash.

Then to use this in my code:

```
FILE *fp = popen("unzip -p filename.docx word/document.xml | sed -e 's/<[^>]\\{1,\\}>//g; s/[^[:print:]]\\{1,\\}//g'", "r");
char buf[1024];

if (fp == NULL) {
    cout << "Error";
}

while (fgets(buf, 1024, fp)) {
    /* do something with buf */
    cout << buf;
}

fclose(fp);
```

**Nothing is printed as a result of this.**

The code works with simple bash commands such as 'ls'

And help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Don't you need to escape each backslash?

Comment: So four backslashes? Like this: `unzip -p filename.docx word/document.xml | sed -e 's/<[^>]\\\\{1,\\\\}>//g; s/[^[:print:]]\\\\{1,\\\\}//g'", "r"`

Comment: Try it? It it works in bash with only 2, then you'll need 4 yes.

Comment: No luck i'm afraid, I actually incorrectly copied the bash script and it originally only had one backslash.

Comment: It's nothing silly like running it in the wrong working directory is it? I suspect it wouldn't print anything (no error) if `filename.docx` didn't exist...

Comment: Maybe, I'm using CLion as an IDE, and that can see the .docx file in the project folder. However if I run the command 'ls' the .docx file isn't printed along with the project files in the same directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>(I assume your program should run on some Linux system, or at least some POSIX one)</sup>

You should at least use `pclose` instead of `fclose` and you should care about the exit code returned by `pclose`.

As commented by [Thab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5292533/thab) don't forget that `\\` is an escape inside [literal strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal) (the C++ compiler is [lexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) that as a single backslash in your string literal constant). You might use `\\\\` or you could use C++11  [raw string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).

<sup>(you certainly should check, e.g. with your debugger, what is the string that `popen` is processing)</sup>

BTW, perhaps that `popen` failed and you did not catch that. Replace

```
if (fp == NULL) {
   cout << "Error";
}
```

<sup>(missing `std::endl`, so the output was *not flushed*)</sup>

with

```
if (fp == nullptr) {
  close << "popen failed:" << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

At last, I am not sure that this is the good approach to convert a `.docx` to `.txt` in batch mode on Linux. I would consider forking a Libreoffice or Openoffice process to do the job (perhaps `libreoffice --headless --cat` and some more options). I don't know all the details, you'll need to [RTFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM).

BTW, you should probably code some small shell script to do the conversion, check and test it in the terminal, and call that shell script using `popen` (hence avoiding a command line with backslashes).

Finally, your C++ code is too C-like. I would suggest using [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) so  replacing

```
while (fgets(buf, 1024, fp)) {
  /* do something with buf */
  cout << buf;
}
```

with

```
char* linbuf = nullptr;
size_t linsiz = 0;
do {
  ssize_t linlen = getline(&linbuf, &linsiz, fp);
  if (linlen<=0) break;
  cout << std::string(linbuf, linlen) << std::endl;
} while (!feof(fp));
free (linbuf), linbuf=nullptr;
```

Of course replace at least your `fclose(fp);` with

```
int excod = pclose(fp);
if (excod != 0) 
  clog << "pclose failed " << excod << std::endl;
```

If you want to know more about the exit code, use [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) related macros on `excod` (e.g. `WIFEXITED`, `WEXITSTATUS`, `WIFSIGNALED`, `WTERMSIG` etc....)

Don't forget to compile with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`) and to use the debugger (`gdb`), [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html), & [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Do care about flushing your [buffers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer) (using [std::flush](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush), [std::endl](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl), [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) etc....) when starting a process with [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) (or [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) or [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) which are `fork`-ing).

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, it’s been very helpful!

When I run the program now, the excod is 0 however nothing is printed as a result of the loop.

I will check all the links you’ve added and hopefully get something working!

I’m running it on OSX v10.11

Comment: Since my last comment i've managed to get it working using your suggestions. Thanks again for the help!